# Как преобразовать сертификат из пары файлов spc и pvk в файл pfx?

Tags: windows, цифровая-подпись

Есть пара файлов `manufacturer.spc` и `manufacturer.pvk`. Как их преобразовать в файл `manufacturer.pfx`, чтобы можно было подписывать файлы через `signtool`?

```
> signtool.exe sign /f manufacturer.pfx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант. Использовать утилиту `pvk2pfx.exe` из `Windows SDK`.

```
> pvk2pfx -pvk файл.pvk -spc файл.spc -pi пароль -pfx файл.pfx
```